# Why "\d+{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,4})?" in RegularExpressionValidator throws Exception: "Nested quantifier {"

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, validation

I have

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="\d+{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,4})?" />
```

but it doesn't' work, parser throws ArgumentException:

> parsing "\d+{1,4}(?:[.,]\d{1,4})?"
>
> Nested quantifier {.

Where is my mistake? I want to allow strings like `xxxx,xxxx` - from 1 to 4 digits and decimal digits are not required, e.g.: `1000`, `99,99`, `0,2498`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
\d{1,4}(?:,\d{1,4})?
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks wrong:

```
\d+{1,4}
```

Should be this:

```
\d{1,4}
```

The `+` means 'one or more' and the `{1,4}` means between one and four. They cannot be used together as it would not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
[.,]?
```

Instead of

```
?:[.,]
```

Comment: I need to make whole right part to be optional, as far as I understand your code makes only `[.,]` to be optional.

Comment: The whole right part was already optional because of your trailing `?`